# Manipulating server side API with state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I built an app in React but later switched to Next.js as my api provider only accepted api calls in the server side, I had built a pagination in react very easily using `useState` and template literals however, I'm kind of confused how I would do the same when API calls are being made on the server side instead.

My server side fetch code is simple and looks like this -

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    try {
        const result = await fetch(`https://exampleapi.com/running?sort=&page={$page_no}&per_page=30&#`);
        const data = await result.json();

        return {
            props: { game: data },
           
        };
    } catch (error) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        return { props: {} };
    }
}


const BoxScore = () => {
  const [page_no, setPage_no] = useState(1);

  const incrementPageNumber = () => {
    setPage_no((page_no) => page_no + 1);
    console.log(page_no);
  };

  const decrementPageNumber = () => {
    if (page_no <= 1) return;
    setPage_no((page_no) => page_no - 1);
  };

 return (
       <div className="container">
        <div className="ctrl-div">
          <button className="ctrl-butts" onClick={incrementPageNumber} >Next</button>
          <button className="ctrl-butts" onClick={decrementPageNumber}> Previous</button>
  
        </div>
  
            <div className="container">
                <h2>Live Games  - </h2>
                <div className="columns is-multiline">
                {game.map(q => (
         <div className="column is-half" key={q.id}>
                <div className="inner">
               {q.name}
</div>
</div>
```

So I want to pass the `{page_no}` into the api request I'm making so my pages can change dynamically, I know I cannot pass the state values into getStaticProps as  mentioned in the docs but as I'm restricted to SSR data fetching only, I'm not sure how to go about with this. Any ideas or resources to tackle this would be very appreciated

Edit - For clarification I've added more code, basically - I'm trying to paginate the data I receive from the API and the API has pagination endpoint so this makes it a little easier, I just am not sure how I would pass the value of my `{page_no}` into the `getStaticProps` method.

Comment: what do you mean by passing `{page_no}` into the api. what is api here?

Comment: the request I'm making in the `fetch`, I would want it to be manipulated dynamically by the state value of `{page_no}`

Comment: So, you want to upload the entire page or only the content?

Comment: @ZurielS.G. I'm not sure I understand, I just want to be able to manipulate the value of `{page_no}` through buttons, which in turn should update the UI and display the newly fetched data.

Comment: This is what we try to do here. Understand each other and our PCs.
Have you tried "set/getStaticPath" will allow you to import data for the page.
Furthermore, how about useHistory hook. There you can manipulate the URL.

Or maybe I didn't understand you properly?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll have a look at those hooks you mentioned as I'm not aware of them yet, Also incase you didn't understand me - I'm just trying to build a pagination for the data being fetched from the API, I want to somehow dynamically pass the value of `{page_no}` into the fetch query so I can fetch page 2, page 3 and so on. Hope that makes it clear

Comment: `getStaticProps` runs once at build time to pre-generate the page. You can either use `getServerSideProps` instead so the page can be pre-rendered on each request with different query params, or handle the pagination logic on the client-side entirely if you want to stick with `getStaticProps`.

Comment: @juliomalves yes I know about SSG vs SSR and do you have any examples or resources that can guide me as to how to achieve client side pagination while using SSG

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch dynamic data in `getStaticProps` because it is run only during build time. (exeption is [incremental-static-regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) but wont work in your case)
You need to use `getServerSideProps` and  read the query params. serverside functions in next.js accepts `context` argument.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    // console.log(context)
    try {
        const { query } = context;
        // since query is an obj, you can add properties withoud defining as let keyword above
        if (!query.page) {
           query.page = "1";
        }

        const result = await fetch(`https://exampleapi.com/running?sort=&page=${query.page}&per_page=30&#`);
        const data = await result.json();

        return {
            props: { game: data },          
            
        };
    } catch (error) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        return { props: {} };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the effort and answer and it gives me some new info but I have a few questions if you don't mind, So can I dynamically change the value of`{query.page}` from say something like press of a button that increments or decrements the value? Note- I would want this button to be rendered on the client side so inside the `return`

Comment: On top of my head, you could store the query.page in useState.  wrap the button with Link component ,` <Link href={`/products?page=${state.page+1}`}>`.

Comment: @juliomalves that is correct. In fact we can not even fetch dynamic data in getStaticProps :)